# How to make a case-insensitive search with Cyrillic letters in ActiveRecord in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a table which contains users by the number of tightenings. I was trying to get only users which made above or equal to certain number of tightenings which administrator inputted. Then administrator will choose first letter of English or Russian alphabet, click the button and only users whose name starts with that letter. However, when I choose Cyrillic letters, lowercase names don't appear in the resulting table while when I choose English letters, lowercase names appear together with the results in capital case. The database is SQLite 3 (Gem version ~> 1.4). How to make lowercase Cyrillic names to appear together with capital case Cyrillic names?

My database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Controller:

```
  def standard
    @users = User.where("users.number_of_tightenings >= ?", params[:standard]).where("users.name LIKE ? collate nocase",  "%#{params[:first_letter_of_name]}%")
  end
```

Routes:

```
  get 'users/top/standard/:standard/:first_letter_of_name', to: 'users#standard'
```

Comment: This code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection. Do not interpolate user input into a SQL string. Use placeholders instead. `User.where("users.number_of_tightenings >= ?", params[:standard]).where("users.name LIKE ? collate nocase",  "%#{params[:first_letter_of_name]}%")`. And the answer here depends completely on what database is in use.

Comment: Thank you, I'll know. Added information about the database.